# Arabic Biblatex with English Title

Tags: biblatex, polyglossia

I am writing a book in Arabic and I am citing English books. I am having issues with citing the Arabic and English books together. Therefore, I decided to translate the English book title and add a custom field in biblatex EngTitle, and include the English title of the book at the end of the reference book. My question are

1. How to add a custom field (engtitle) to Biblatex and show it the reference?
2. How to translate the word **edition** in the reference to Arabic (See code below)
3. If you have a better idea to handle the Arabic and English bibliography in the same document, please share it with me.

My Code

```
                \documentclass{article}
            \RequirePackage{filecontents}
            
            \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
                @Book{gardner2011frames,
                    title     = {أطر العقل: نظرية الذكاءات المتعددة},
                    publisher = {هاشيت المملكة المتحدة},
                    author    = {هوارد جاردنر},
                    edition   = {3},
                    date      = {2011},
                    keywords  = {english},
                    engtitle   = {Frames of Mind: The Theory of Multiple Intelligences},
                }
                @Book{Life2020,
                    title     = {لايف كوتشينج : الطريق إلى العالمية},
                    publisher = {دار سما للنشر والتوزيع},
                    year      = {2020},
                    author    = {كمال جابري},
                    keywords  = {arabic},
                }
            \end{filecontents}
            
            \usepackage{polyglossia}
            \setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
            \setmainlanguage[calendar=islamic]{arabic}
            \setotherlanguage{english}
            \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Scheherazade}
            
            \usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber,sorting=none]{biblatex}
            \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
            \defbibheading{bibempty}{}
            
            
            \begin{document}
            
            
            
            \renewcommand\bibname{المراجع}
            \nocite{*}
            \printbibliography
            
            \end{document}
```